# xamarin connect to bluetooth ble. The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I want to send a data in my bluetooth device, I used several solutions but none works because I receive this notification.
Skipped 730 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I don't use an Android emulator but my phone.

```
 private  void SendCommandButton_Clicked(object sender, 
         EventArgs e)
         {
                    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($" 
         {CommandTxt.Text}\r\n");
                               
         }
          public  void WriteData (byte[] data)
          {
            try
            {
                if (sendCharacteristic != null)
                {
                      Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
                    {
                        var bytes =  
          sendCharacteristic.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($" 
                {CommandTxt.Text}\r\n"));
                    });
                   
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex)
            {
                Output.Text = ex.StackTrace; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: "none works because I receive this notification" - why do you think these are related?   Where does `WriteData` actually get called?

Comment: when I try to access this page faster, I have fewer frames. The WriteData is a send on a device type Arduino. In the method it does not pass in wrestling, the only thing is that it has stopped, too much work on the main thread, but if I use an async, I get the same result.

Comment: Have you try to use async await to wait it?

Comment: Async method not Run ,it’s a same.

Comment: Without more code, i am not sure why it does not work. You could debug it to find which line skip it.